# Invalid Block instance

Tags: customer, login, forms, blocks

I'm having an annoying issue with Magento. My exceptions log contentiously pop up this error. Its rather annoying and I was wondering if anyone else had this issue. I'm using Magento 1.7.

```
2014-10-13T14:06:12+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login' in /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/cantrelldrug.com/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(27335): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(27277): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Mage_Customer_B...', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(26496): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('Mage_Customer_B...', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(26195): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(26834): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<div id="left">...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(10616): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<div id="left">...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2237): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2177): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('cms_page', true)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(13160): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2237): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2181): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#16 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/app/design/frontend/cantrelldrug/cantrelldrug_theme/template/page/1column.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(3223): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(3254): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/cantre...')
#19 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(3268): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#includes/src/__default.php(27395): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#includes/src/__default.php(13553): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(10913): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(10828): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '10')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '10')
#26 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(13582): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(17927): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(17484): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(20061): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

I'm just wondering if anyone has any clue. I've done searches and couldn't find that particular string. I'm trying to bring down my error logging. Thanks for any helpful information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of these lines

```
#0 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(27335): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(27277): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Mage_Customer_B...', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/jvp7-fwpk.accessdomain.com/#/includes/src/__default.php(26496): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('Mage_Customer_B...', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
```

It seams that you have a cms page or static block (most probably page) that contains this:

```
{{block type="Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login" ....}}
```

Look in the database, in the table `cms_page` or cms_block for records that have `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login` in the content column. Then you will know what page you need to edit to change the content.

Comment: You, sir, are awesome! Found it!! Now thanks for your help! Most of the work done on our site was done by a consulting firm. I've been hired to clean up their mess they created.

Answer (score 2):

You are using somewhere `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login` and because Magentos autoloader doesn't find the method, because it looks for a file called `login.php` instead of `Login.php`, this error happens.

Just grep/search for `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login` and fix this bug.

Even better, change the code, to use magentos factory methods `createBlock('customer/form_login')`

Comment: You didn't fully read what I posted. I've SEARCHED and couldn't find that particular string. Namely Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login.

Comment: Sorry. I was in a rush :-/